# Onclick, only parent div not subdiv

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm playing around with building a basic modal window and i want it do dissapear when i click the edges. So my problem in it's most basic form:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;" onclick="hideAll()">
    Hide all onclick.
    <div style="width:100px;height:100px;">
        does not hide all onclick
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to achieve this? To use unnested divs? html/css magic?

Comment: `hideAll()` why have you not posted this js function? and onobtrusive javascript should be used and most prefered way.

Comment: _html/css magic?_ what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hide the parent tag, it automatically hides the childen tag as well, You should first contain the child div into variable and after that hide the parent div and append that stored child div into  parent tag something like this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="result">
    <div style="width:100%;height:100%;" id="parentDiv" onclick="hideAll()">
        Hide all onclick.
        <div style="width:100px;height:100px;" id="childDiv">
            does not hide all onclick
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**javaScript**

```
function hideAll(){
    var childDiv = document.getElementById('childDiv'); //contain child div
    var parDiv = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
    parDiv.style.display = 'none'; //hide parent div
    parDiv.parentNode.appendChild(childDiv); //append child div
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7RMb7/)

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;" class="outerModal">
    Hide all onclick.
    <div style="width:100px;height:100px;">
        does not hide all onclick
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".outerModal", function(evt) {  //listen for clicks
    var target = $(evt.target ||evt.srcElement);  //get the element that was clicked on
    if (target.is(".outerModal")) {  //make sure it was not a child that was clicked. 
        //hide dialog
    }
});
```

**Example:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RH8H/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "parentDiv" is to be the background and "childDiv" is to be the actual modal content, the best way I have found is to separate the divs entirely.

HTML

```
<div id="parentDiv" onclick="hideAll()">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="childDiv" >
   does not hide all onclick
</div>
```

Javascript using jQuery

```
function hideAll(){
    /* The Parent Div will hide everything when clicked, but the child won't */
    $('#childDiv').fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('#parentDiv').fadeOut(1000);
    });
}
```

CSS

```
#parentDiv {
    background: black;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#childDiv { 
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 101
}
```

## [Here is a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/mysticalnomad/9aff8/)

Hope this helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eZp9D/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#parentDiv').click(function (e) {
         if ($(e.target).prop('id') == "parentDiv") {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i added id's to the Div's btw.

Comment: yes.. the parent will hide all, the child will not.... wait are you saying you want to hide ONLY the parent and not its children???? that's a different question if so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic jQuery and style it accordingly with CSS. 
Check [this example](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

If you want to have it disappear by clicking outside of the dialog window, make sure that onClick you perform this action:

```
$( "#dialog_id" ).dialog( "close" );
```